# I'm trying to add a small graph in document . However, it returns Package tikz Error: Giving up on this path. Did you forge t a semicolon?

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, draw

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[black] (0,0) -- (3,0)
    node[ pos=0.01,label=below:{-2}]{|}
    node[ pos=0.16,label=above:{+}]{}
    node[ pos=0.33,label=below:{0}]{o}
    node[ pos=0.48,label=below:{-}]{}
    node[ pos=0.66,label=below:{2}]{o}
    node[ pos=0.81,label=above:{+}]{}
    node[ pos=0.98,label=below:{3}]{|}
   \end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). In the future, consider providing a [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that) in order for people to be able to reproduce your problem and help you. However, here, the error is pretty straightforward : did you try adding a semicolon after your last `{|}`? Each TikZ command must be terminated with a semicolon, which is what the error tells you.

Comment: Thank you. I just found my errors. I forget ";" end of section.